# OpenCV 3.x Documentation in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, opencv3.0

I've compile OCV 3.4 on my Mac. Everything runs fine, PyCharm works, QT5 bindings are fine.
I have one problem: Don't know how to add the documentation for OCV in PyCharm.

I know it's under ExternalDocumentation but how do I specify the right path???

I have the generate doc files on my HD (OpenCV/doc/html and OpenCV/doc/javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

I have installed `opencv-python` via `pip install opencv-python` (see https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/ for more details) and now I can see all the docs with Ctrl+Q shortcut. The only problem, I was not able to get a nice formatting:

[Help on openCV function in the Documentation tool window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzbqZ.png)

Still it simplifies things a lot comparing with the manual installation I had before.